@ant-design/react-native Input field add border-bottom default and i want to remove it
[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have tried to add borderBottomWidth and borderColor but it is not working
              import React from "react";
import { ScrollView, Text } from "react-native";
import {
  Form,
  Input,
  Picker,
  Radio,
  Switch,
  Button,
  Provider,
} from "@ant-design/react-native";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
const fields = [
  {
    label: "Email Address",
    placeholder: "Enter email address",
    name: "email",
    type: "text",
    validations: [{ required: true, message: "Email is required" }],
  },
  {
    label: "Password",
    placeholder: "Enter password",
    name: "password",
    type: "text",
    validations: [{ required: true, message: "Password is required" }],
  },
  {
    label: "Gender",
    name: "gender",
    type: "radio",
    options: [
      { label: "Male", value: "male" },
      { label: "Female", value: "female" },
      { label: "Females", value: "females" },
    ],
    validations: [{ required: true, message: "Please select a gender" }],
  },
  {
    label: "Age",
    placeholder: "Enter age",
    name: "age",
    type: "number",
    validations: [{ required: true, message: "Password is required" }],
  },
  {
    label: "Default",
    name: "isDefault",
    type: "switch",
  },
];

const FormExample = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const onSubmit = () => {
    form.submit();
  };

  const onFinish = (values) => {};

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {};

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Provider>
        <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
          <Form
            name="dynamicForm"
            form={form}
            onFinish={onFinish}
            onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
            layout="horizontal"
          >
            <FieldItems fields={fields} />
            <Button type="primary" onPress={onSubmit}>
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </ScrollView>
      </Provider>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default FormExample;

const FieldItems = ({ fields }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {fields.map((field, index) => {
        switch (field.type) {
          case "text":
            return (
              <Form.Item
                key={index}
                name={field.name}
                rules={field.validations}
                label={field.label}
                required={field.required}
              >
                <Input placeholder={field.placeholder} />
              </Form.Item>
            );
          case "number":
            return (
              <Form.Item
                key={index}
                name={field.name}
                rules={field.validations}
                label={field.label}
                required={field.required}
              >
                <Input type="number" placeholder={field.placeholder} />
              </Form.Item>
            );
          case "switch":
            return (
              <Form.Item
                key={index}
                name={field.name}
                label={field.label}
                valuePropName="checked"
                wrapperStyle={{ alignItems: "flex-end" }}
                initialValue={true}
              >
                <Switch />
              </Form.Item>
            );
          case "radio":
            return (
              <Form.Item
                key={index}
                name={field.name}
                rules={field.validations}
                label={field.label}
                required={field.validations?.some((v) => v.required)}
              >
                <Radio.Group>
                  {field.options.map((option, i) => (
                    <Radio key={i} value={option.value}>
                      {option.label}
                    </Radio>
                  ))}
                </Radio.Group>
              </Form.Item>
            );
          case "picker":
            return (
              <Form.Item
                key={index}
                name={field.name}
                rules={field.validations}
                label={field.label}
              >
                <Picker data={field.options} cols={field.cols}>
                  <Input placeholder={field.placeholder} />
                </Picker>
              </Form.Item>
            );
          default:
            return null;
        }
      })}
    </>
  );
};


I have tried all the available styles to remove the border but seems like none of them working.
I have gone through their documentation but couldn't find any useful solution.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/yrMk5FV0.png

It looks like you can't customize the style.
instead you can add style to the input item using style prop

You can find more info here

I have tried all the available styles to remove the bottom border, i have set borderWidth to 0 but seems like it is not working too.

Can you provide the entire component you wrote?
